# Add new column to dataframe, based on values at specific rows within that dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

Suppose I have a dataframe such as the below

```
people.dat <- data.frame("ID" = c(2001, 1001, 2005, 2001 5000), "Data" 
= c(100, 300, 500, 900, 200))
```

Which looks something like this

```
+------+------+
|  ID  | Data |
+------+------+
| 2001 |  100 |
| 1001 |  300 |
| 2005 |  500 |
| 2001 |  900 |
| 5000 |  200 |
+------+------+
```

Suppose the first thing I do is work out how many unique ID values are in the dataframe (this is necessary, due to the size of the real dataset in question)

```
unique_ids <- sort(c(unique(people.dat$ID)))
```

Which gives

```
[1] 1001 2001 2005 5000
```

Where I get stuck is that I would like to add a new column, say "new_id", which looks at the "ID" value in the dataframe and evaluates its position in unique_ids, and assigns positional value (so the column "new_id" consists of values at each row which range from 1:length(unique_ids)

An example of the output would be as follows

```
+------+------+--------+
|  ID  | Data | new_id |
+------+------+--------+
| 2001 |  100 |   2    |
| 1001 |  300 |   1    |
| 2005 |  500 |   3    |
| 2001 |  900 |   1    |
| 5000 |  200 |   4    |
+------+------+--------+
```

I thought about using a for loop with if statements, but my first attempts didn't quite hit the mark. Although, if I just wanted to replace "ID" with a sequential value, the following code would work (but where I get stuck is that I want to keep ID, but add another "new_id" column)

```
for (i in 1:48){
  people.dat$ID[people.dat$ID == unique_ids[i]] <- i
}
```

Thank you for any help. Hope I have made the question as clear as possible (although I struggled to phrase some of it, so please let me know if there is anything specific that needs clarifying)

Comment: `people.dat$new_id  <- match(people.dat$ID, unique_ids)`

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. Sorry for the duplicate, I couldn't find the right words to describe my problem, so struggled to find the other post when searching

Answer (score 0):

This is more like a `'rank'` problem

```
people$rank=as.numeric(factor(people$ID))
people
    ID Data rank
1 2001  100    2
2 1001  300    1
3 2005  500    3
4 2001  900    2
5 5000  200    4
```

Comment: why even `rank`? `as.numeric(factor(people.dat$ID))` gives the same output.

Comment: @RonakShah yep you are right